# Textbox search accented characters problem?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for information on datagrid using textbox assign `textchanged_event`.

The problem I encountered was that when I typed the `characters with a accented` then datagrid would blink (it seems every change would be recorded in the textbox not just the final result).

*Example*: when typing `"khang"`

If I continue to type the letter `"a"`, in english it will result in `"khanga"` and everything goes well, but in some languages it should be `"khâng"` and I see in textchanged it will take many steps as:

`"khang" -> "khang•" -> "khang" -> "khan" -> "kha" -> "khâ" ->"khân"->"khâng"`
in this moment, the datagrid will blink continuously.
what should I do to textchanged only handle the final result?

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee that you only handle the final value unless you use a `Button.Click` instead of a `TextBox.TextChanged`, or maybe force the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and handle the `TextBox.KeyDown` or the like. What you can do instead is ensure that you only act on the `TextChanged` if no other `TextChanged` has occurred for a specific length of time by using a `Timer`. That way, the delay is not so great that the user really feels it but it is long enough to allow multiple keystrokes without acting on them in between.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    'Start/restart the Timer every time the Text changes.
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Perform filter when time expires.
    Timer1.Stop()
    BindingSource1.Filter = $"SomeColumn LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'"
End Sub
```

It's up to you want you set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to but I'd be looking at around 300. You can do a bit of experimentation to find what gives you the best balance.